# Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, web-applications, scriptlet

I have a javascript function that makes an ajax get request. This is a legacy application and I am limited to what I can do . I cannot use jquery.

As you can see I am using scriptlet to access object in request scope. I am trying to alert the value returned by the scriptlet but I keep getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

"google" is the value returned by the scriptlet which is the expected/correct value.

```
function getLinkAddress(linkClicked){
    httpGetUrl("http://www.google.com");    
    alert(<%=((DynaActionForm) request.getAttribute("ipacForm")).get("url").toString() %>);
}       

function httpGetUrl(theUrl){
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "?screenName=LinkAddress&buttonName=get", false);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
```

As you can see in the image below of my debugging console, the value inside the alert() correctly evaluates to "google.com"

[image]

Comment: you forgot the quotation marks. Its a string not a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to alert a string, but your code thinks its a variable, thus getting the "not defined" error. You need to surround your answer with quotes:

```
alert("google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I will accept you answer in 10 minutes and after that I will go drown myself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `window.alert` method expects a string, and you're passing an undefined value for it. The browser will try to find a global variable `google`, and a property into `google` named `com`, so it won't find, and it will throw an error.

What you want is to alert a string `'google.com'`, so you need quotation marks:

```
alert('<%=((DynaActionForm) request.getAttribute("ipacForm")).get("url").toString() %>');
```